# Add event listener to ref from React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

The React context provider sets a `ref` that is used by another component to set a blur event listener. The problem is that a blur event does not trigger the listener.

Code extract for the context provider.

```
...
export function useEditorContext(): EditorContextProps {
    return useContext(EditorContext) as EditorContextProps;
}

export default function EditorProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const historyState = useMemo(createEmptyHistoryState, []);
    const context = { historyState, ref };
    return (
        <EditorContext.Provider value={context}>
            <div ref={ref}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </EditorContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

The goal is to attach the listener in a Lexical plugin.

```
const { historyState, ref } = useEditorContext();

const blurHandler = (event: FocusEvent) => {
    console.log('Blurred');
};

useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    if (element) {
        element.addEventListener('blur', blurHandler, false);
    } else return;

    return () => {
        element.removeEventListener('blur', blurHandler);
    };
}, [ref.current]); // eslint-disable-line
```

I have run the code with logging and tried several solutions/answers for `useRef` and `addEventListener` but none worked in the above scenario. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur event does not bubble, but you can use the related focusout event instead to handle child elements losing focus.

```js
if (element) {
  element.addEventListener('focusout', blurHandler);
} else return;

return () => element.removeEventListener('focusout', blurHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not expect this since the blur event from children does bubble to onBlur listener directly in the DIV in the context provider.